# facebook login with different domains

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I'm implementing on my site the Facebook login and I'm having a problem.
When people access my site through the domain www.1001loveletters.com works fine, but if they type 1001loveletters.com it doesn't work.
In the configuration of the API I have http://www.1001loveletters.com domain, so that works fine, but I did not find a place to insert a secondary domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `domain` just write this: `1001loveletters.com` and both the urls shall work.

Comment: Just remove the `domain` entry, its not required

Comment: The App Domain is empty, but the Site URL can't be empty.

Comment: Of course site url cant be empty. I know. Is it not working? Can you tell me the steps so that I can reproduce this